# Unwanted buttons being added to Tkinter quiz

Tags: python, tkinter

the code here is a quiz. At the moment the code creates a window with the questions and answers and when the correct answer is pressed (the larger button), it creates another window with an "ok" button on it and a message saying "correct". Once the "ok" button is clicked, the question window will refresh with another question. When you click the correct answer again, the window will appear again with the "ok" button except it will have two buttons. This will keep happening, adding one more "ok" button everytime the code loops. Is there anyway to fix it?

(I was also told that there was simpler way to do this as a whole, where I actually generate the questions and answers first, then put them in list and then randomly call them so that I can make sure the questions don't repeat. Then I could have the the "correct" message appear in the same window and disable the buttons so I can't click another answer. The the message would change to the next question with new answers. Is this possible? If so it would be a massive help).

Thanks for your help.

```
def quiz_easy():

    global question 
    questions = []
    correctanswers = []
    possibleanswer1s = []
    possibleanswer2s = []
    possibleanswer3s = []
    easy_questions = open("sup.txt", "r")



    count = 1
    for line in easy_questions:
        if count == 1:
            questions.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 2:
            correctanswers.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 3:
            possibleanswer1s.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 4:
            possibleanswer2s.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 5:
            possibleanswer3s.append(line.rstrip())
        if count == 5:
            count = 1
        else:
            count = count + 1
    print(questions)
    print (correctanswers)

    randno1 = random.randint(0,len(questions)-1)
    master = Tk()
    text = Text(master)
    text.insert(INSERT, questions[randno1])
    text.insert(END, "?")
    text.pack()
    text.tag_add("here","5.0", "1.4")
    text.tag_add("start", "1.8", "1.13")
    correct = Tk()
    text = Text(correct)
    text.insert(INSERT, "Correct")
    text.insert(END, "!")
    text.pack()

    correct.withdraw()

    def close_wrong():
        quiz_easy()
        wrong.destroy()


    def correctans():
        correct.deiconify()
        master.withdraw()

        print("Hello")
##This part here is the recurring "ok" button which needs to be fixed
        okbutton = Button(correct, text="Ok", command=close_correct)
        if not okbutton.winfo_exists():
            okbutton = Button(correct, text="Ok", command=close_correct)

        okbutton.pack()


    def wrong():

        wrong = Tk()
        text = Text(wrong)
        text.insert(INSERT, "Wrong")
        text.insert(END, "!")
        text.pack()
    def well_done():

        welldone = Tk()
        text = Text(welldone)
        text.insert(INSERT, "WHATYOUTALKINGTOME")
        text.insert(END, "?!")
        text.pack()
        okbutton = Button(welldone, text="Ok", command=game_loop)

        okbutton.pack()

    def close_correct():

        global question

        if question == 5:
           well_done()
           correct.destroy()
        else:
            #quiz_easy()
            master.deiconify()
            correct.withdraw()



    randno2 = random.randint(0,23)
    if randno2 == 0:
        answer1button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 1:
        answer1button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 2:
        answer1button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 3:
        answer1button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 4:
        answer1button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 5:
        answer1button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 6:
        answer2button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 7:
        answer2button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 8:
        answer2button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 9:
        answer2button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 10:
        answer2button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 11:
        answer2button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 12:
        answer3button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 13:
        answer3button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 14:
        answer3button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 15:
        answer3button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 16:
        answer3button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 17:
        answer3button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer4button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 18:
        answer4button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 19:
        answer4button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 20:
        answer4button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 21:
        answer4button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 22:
        answer4button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1
    elif randno2 == 23:
        answer4button = Button(master, text=correctanswers[randno1], width=20, command=correctans)
        answer3button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer1s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer2button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer2s[randno1], command=wrong)
        answer1button = Button(master, text=possibleanswer3s[randno1], command=wrong)
        question = question + 1

    answer1button.pack()
    answer2button.pack()
    answer3button.pack()
    answer4button.pack()

    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Reduce your question, it's too long. Go to the point, where you need help, and just ask for it, post eventually code necessary for us to understand what the heck is going on ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never make more than one Tk object in one application. That's what Toplevel widgets are for. Now, you're left with two options to correct your error. One is to make one toplevel object when the program starts and show/hide it, and the other is to make a new toplevel every time it needs to show, but then destroy it. For the sake of simplicity, I'll demonstrate the second - here is your function edited to work (hopefully):

```
def well_done():
    welldone = Toplevel()
    text = Text(welldone)
    text.insert(INSERT, "WHATYOUTALKINGTOME")
    text.insert(END, "?!")
    text.pack()
    okbutton = Button(welldone, text="Ok", command=(lambda: welldone.destroy() or game_loop()))

    okbutton.pack()
```

The lambda trick is kind of a dirty one, but is neccessary if you are not willing to use a global reference for `welldone`.

As for the second part of your question, I'd use the shuffle function from the random module. Zip your question and answer lists to a list of tuples (`zip(questions, correctanswers, possibleanswer1s, possibleanswer2s, possibleanswer3s)` or `list(zip(...))` case of Python 3), and then shuffle the result. Iterate through it and fill in the question and answers:

```
zipped=zip(questions, correctanswers, possibleanswer1s, possibleanswer2s, possibleanswer3s)
for q, ca, ica1, ica2, ica3 in random.shuffle(zipped):
    text.insert(INSERT, q)
    answer1button = Button(master, text=ca, width=20, command=correctans)
    answer2button = Button(master, text=ica1, command=wrong)
    answer3button = Button(master, text=ica2, command=wrong)
    answer4button = Button(master, text=ica3, command=wrong)
    question = question + 1
```

For the third part of the question, I will not provide any code because the question is too loose. You can add a Label or a Text widget and use pack_forget() (or grid_forget() if you use grid) to "unpack" it. Of course, you can pack it again normally.